# Implement a Custom Start date/End date Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

We want to use `Fullcalendar` [monthly] view . we want to implement a calendar with

1. current month as October
2. which starts from 10 Oct 2013 to 20th Nov 2013 {42-DAY MONTH WINDOW}

I don't find any input parameters to be provided to calendar which takes Start date[20 Oct 2013] and end date[20 Nov 2013].

Please guide me out

Comment: Are trying to say that you want just want to load 1 month of events to be mapped every time you prev,next the calendar in month view?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally get what you are trying to achieve, but you could use the 
[Go To date](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/) function on document.ready to jump to October.
then only allow using the calendar next button once - 
(hide the previous button on start, than after clicking the next button hide it and show the previous button and vice versa).